# How to make UUID() function, statement-based replication safe?

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm trying the copy and generating `UUID()`s on the fly for exiting data when executing A insert from select.

How can I make the `UUID()` function statement-based replication safe?
Can I somehow use the old ID's from the primary table or at least save them for the entire operation? so the replica will have the same IDs?

```
INSERT INTO table_name (number,REPLACE(UUID(),………(SELECT ….));
```

which means primary and any its slave have inconsistent data for `table_name`, because of the `UUID` func.

Comment: Any reason why you can't assign the `UUID()` result to a variable which you then use in the `INSERT`?

Comment: Have you considered using 'binlog_format=ROW'?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question, but if you select the uuid from the parent, Whats the problem?

```
Insert into t (c1, c2,..., cn)
Select 36, 'abc', c3,... FROM parent
```